# Alarm taking too long to trigger

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have a mostly working alarm that functions perfectly except for one aspect: The time that I have set for the alarm to trigger is not always the time that it triggers at.

I was thinking for a while that maybe the alarm ran in seconds, not milliseconds. After rereading the documentation, this thought was dismissed.

I'm going to post the important code now before I explain a bit more:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startAlarm(findViewById(R.id.reset));
        Log.d("test", "reseting");
    }
};

public void startAlarm(View view) {
    //setup
    EditText nameInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    EditText firstAlertInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.firstAlertInput);
    EditText intervalInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.intervalInput);
    EditText descriptionInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.descriptionInput);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    //Need to parse and format the offset now, before intent is created, then attach it to the intent.
    //HERE I NEED TO GET THE OFFSET AND CONVERT INTO MILLISECONDS
    EditText hoursInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.hoursInput);
    EditText minutesInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.minutesInput);
    EditText secondsInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.secondsInput);
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    try {
        hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursInput.getText().toString()) * 3600000;
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesInput.getText().toString()) * 60000;
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsInput.getText().toString()) * 1000;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

    }
    int offsetMillis = hours + minutes + seconds;
    //HERE: Randomly Generate the offset, add or subtract it when alarm is set. Make sure to attach the opposite to the PI so that the next alarm will trigger at te correct default time
    int offsetRandomMillis = 0;

    if(offsetMillis != 0){
        Random offsetRandom = new Random();
        int oneOrNegativeOne = (offsetRandom.nextBoolean()) ? 1 : -1;
        offsetRandomMillis = offsetRandom.nextInt(offsetMillis) * oneOrNegativeOne;
    }

    //Creates new offset alarm structure
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", nameInput.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("description", descriptionInput.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Creates new recursion alarm structure
    Intent intent2 = new Intent("RESET_ALARM");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 000, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    //Stores old offset alarm details
    editor.putString("oldName", nameInput.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("oldDescription", descriptionInput.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();

    //Finishes new offset alarm details
    int[] times = parseTime(firstAlertInput.getText().toString());
    times[0] = times[0] * 3600000;
    times[1] = times[1] * 60000;
    long millis = times[0] + times[1];
    int[] intervalTimes = parseTime(intervalInput.getText().toString());
    intervalTimes[0] = intervalTimes[0] * 3600000;
    intervalTimes[1] = intervalTimes[1] * 60000;
    long intervalMillis = intervalTimes[0] + intervalTimes[1];

    //New offset alarm set
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + millis + intervalMillis + offsetRandomMillis, pendingIntent);
    //New Recursion alarm set
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + millis + intervalMillis, pendingIntent2);

    Log.d("test", "OFFSET: " + String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis() + millis + intervalMillis + offsetRandomMillis) / 1000));
    Log.d("test", "NOOFFSET: " + String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis() + millis + intervalMillis) / 1000));
}

private int[] parseTime(String input){
    int[] times = new int[2];
    String[] split = input.split(":");
    for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
        times[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
    }
    return times;
}
```

NOTE: These are both in the same class, and I am excluding irrelevant parts of that same class.

So here is what is happening: After I clear all alarms and set new ones, those alarms trigger at the correct time. When the broadcastReceiver sets the new alarms, these alarms trigger 5-20 seconds late. All subsequent alarms that it sets also trigger late, but they trigger 5-20 seconds later than the previous alarms. As you can see, the alarm ends up triggering far fewer times than in should.

Also, note that this experiment was tested with an interval value of 1 minute, meaning that each alarm should have triggered one minute after it was set. I know there is also code that determines and parses an offset, but I have no set a value for that, so it doesn't affect the time. I printed this value among many other values, so I know that this works.

I'm frustrated because I see no reason why this should fail. The current log.d statements in the code that I posted are just to show when a new alarm is set and the time in which both alarms should go off (one alarm is suppose to trigger a notification, this one that adds the offset. The other triggers without the offset and sets the new alarms. Sorry if I confused you.). These values are correct, so that is not an issue.

My suspicion at the moment comes from another experiment that I performed. I continually clicked the button that first runs the startAlarm method. This displayed the time in milliseconds that the alarms that were set should have triggered. I expected this number to rise constantly as 1000 milliseconds must pass in one second. This was not the case however. The number rose slowly, about 10 every few. This was a very unexpected behavior. Can someone please explain the reason for this in their answer as well? Thanks.

My current suspicion is that I have failed to convert something into milliseconds or into seconds. But, looking through the code and logging variables, I don't know that this is the issue. The milliseconds that pass seem to be funky, so I don't know what is up.

Comment: On which OS you are testing?

Comment: My phone is a nexus 5 running android 6.0.1. This is what I am testing on.. The SDK of my project is currently only 6.0.0.

I'll check your code when I get home tonight.

Comment: Try to use this
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); } else { alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); } 
It will resolve your issue.